# Xcode 5 Just Corrupted Every xib

Tags: xcode, crash, xib, nib

I was uploading an update for an app using Xcode, and it failed because I forgot to change the version number.  I went into Xcode and made that one change, clicked Archive again, and it failed, giving me this message:

```
CompileXIB LinkControllerViewController2.xib
    cd /Users/candacebrassfield/Desktop/XCodeProjects/SEC
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    export XCODE_DEVELOPER_USR_PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/..
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool --errors --warnings --notices --minimum-deployment-target 6.1 --output-format human-readable-text --compile /Users/candacebrassfield/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SEC-ezfrsbwjhyjqesbeiphpofmlamlq/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/SEC/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/SEC.app/LinkControllerViewController2.nib /Users/candacebrassfield/Desktop/XCodeProjects/SEC/LinkControllerViewController2.xib

dyld: Symbol not found: _ccmode_gcrdfisflize
  Referenced from: /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
  Expected in: /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
 in /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
2014-07-21 17:34:33.467 ibtoold[11137:507] Init failed: Error Domain=IBMessageChannelErrorDomain Code=1 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (IBMessageChannelErrorDomain error 1.)"
2014-07-21 17:34:33.468 ibtoold[11137:507] [MT] DVTAssertions: Warning in /SourceCache/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouch/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouch-5038/InterfaceBuilder/Utilities/IBObjectMarshalling.m:314
Details:  IBAttachToCocoaTouchTool() failed: Error Domain=com.apple.InterfaceBuilder Code=-1 "Interface Builder encountered an error communicating with the iOS Simulator." UserInfo=0x7fa72629e6d0 {NSUnderlyingError=0x7fa726192530 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (IBMessageChannelErrorDomain error 1.)", NSLocalizedDescription=Interface Builder encountered an error communicating with the iOS Simulator., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Please check Console.app for crash reports for "Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool" for further information., NSLocalizedFailureReason="Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool" (11149) failed to launch and exited with status (null), signal 5.}
Function: IBMessageChannelCocoaTouchToolProxy *IBAttachToCocoaTouchToolFailingGracefully(IBCocoaTouchTargetRuntime *__strong, NSError *__autoreleasing *)
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fa723c19c30>{name = (null), num = 1}
Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool failed with exit code
```

I have no idea what any of this means.  Also, now when I try to go to any of my xib files, it crashes Xcode, and gives me this, in part.

```
Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 5B1008
ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouch/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouch-5038/InterfaceBuilder/Utilities/IBObjectMarshalling.m:36
Details:  Failed to launch cocoa touch tool: Error Domain=com.apple.InterfaceBuilder Code=-1 "Interface Builder encountered an error communicating with the iOS Simulator." UserInfo=0x7ffcf7b58b00 {NSUnderlyingError=0x7ffcf623f2c0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (IBMessageChannelErrorDomain error 1.)", NSLocalizedDescription=Interface Builder encountered an error communicating with the iOS Simulator., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Please check Console.app for crash reports for "Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool" for further information., NSLocalizedFailureReason="Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool" (11174) failed to launch and exited with status (null), signal 5.}
Object:   <NSThread: 0x7ffcf1615580>
Method:   -cocoaTouchToolForTargetRuntime:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7ffcf1615580>{name = (null), num = 1}
Hints:   None
```

I literally did nothing between successful builds, except to change the version number, so I have no clue where this is coming from.

Comment: Hi user717452, Did you get any solution? I am also facing same issue.

Comment: @Gagan_iOS sorry took so long to reply.  I rebooted my computer a couple times and it worked just fine.

Comment: Thanks. I upgraded my XCode version upto 6.0 & it works.